# Java bean validation vs XSD validation for @Pattern.List

Tags: java, validation, xsd, bean-validation

Using krasa-jaxb-tools jaxb-plugin, I generated following:

From XSD schema:

```
<xs:simpleType name="SomethingId">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="small\.123[A-Za-z0-9\.]{0,27}"/>
        <xs:pattern value="SMALL\.123[A-Za-z0-9\.]{0,27}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I got annotated element:

```
    @XmlElement(name = "SomethingId", required = true)
    @NotNull
    @Pattern.List({
    @Pattern(regexp = "small\\.123[A-Za-z0-9\\.]{0,27}"),
    @Pattern(regexp = "SMALL\\.123[A-Za-z0-9\\.]{0,27}")
})
protected String somethingId;
```

Default validator (provider is Apache):

```
 ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        this.validator = factory.getValidator();
```

Using JAXB, I successfully produced valid XML (which passes XSD validation - including the format of above-mentioned string).

But if I try to validate string as mentioned above using Bean Validation it throws error - if it is written "small123" it says it should be capitalized (failing *SMALL.123[A-Za-z0-9.]{0,27}* regex) and vice versa.

The conclusion is that XSD validation treats pattern list as if logical OR was implied, and bean validation treats them as logical AND.

Since this event occurred only once in my code, I managed to fix it (quick and dirty), but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Is this a problem with the plugin (which generated wrong annotations), with validator or something else (which I fail to notice)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the Problem is with the plugin.

see here
https://github.com/krasa/krasa-jaxb-tools/issues/41 (fixed and merged in 1.5)
and here
https://github.com/krasa/krasa-jaxb-tools/issues/54

If you are not using 1.5, maybe updating fixes your problem. 
In other cases you have to wait for a merge and release of issue 54 or apply this fix in your local repo.